# "Leider Gottes"

Tags: etymology, phrase

Jeder hat diese Wendung bestimmt schon einmal gehört, für mich ist sie Synonym zu "leider", vielleicht ein wenig stärker.

Aber woher kommt sie? Und welche Konstruktion ist das? Und hatte sie ursprünglich vielleicht eine andere Bedeutung?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Laut [Duden.de](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/leider) ist die Wendung *entstanden aus (bei dem) Leiden Gottes* und soll den Umstand ausdrücken, dass [selbst Gott beim Anblick dieses Vorfalls leidet](http://www.elia-gemeinschaft.de/wordpress/2006/12/21/peters-gedanken/totaaal-ernst-gemeint/deutsch-zum-abgewohnen-heute-%E2%80%9Cleider-gottes%E2%80%9D/comment-page-1#comment-1809).

Answer (score 9):

Im [etymologischen Wörterbuch des Deutschen nach Pfeifer](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=leider&view=1) findet sich folgender, interessanter Eintrag:

> **leider** Adv. 'bedauerlicherweise, unglücklicherweise', ahd. *leidōr* (9. Jh.), mhd. *leider*, mnd. *lēder*, *leider*, eigentl. Komparativ des Adverbs (ahd. *leido*, mhd. *leide*, s. oben) mit verstärkender Funktion, seit Beginn der Überlieferung oft als Ausruf des Bedauerns und der Klage gebraucht; auffällig ist die steigernde Fügung **leider Gottes** (17. Jh.), die nach *ANDRESEN* in: ZfdA (1886) 417f. wahrscheinlich auf Umbildung der Beteuerungsformel *(beim) Leiden Gottes* beruht.

Demnach ist "*leider"* in der Wendung *"Leider Gottes"* nicht der noch übrig gebliebene Komparatativ des heute nicht mehr benutzten Adverbs "*[leide](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=leide)*" in der Bedeutung von *"bedauerlicherweise"*, sondern eine (umgangssprachliche) Verkürzung von

> Beim Leiden Gottes